# Derivative wrt. to Lie bracket.

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a matrix Lie group, $\frak{g}$ the corresponding Lie algebra,
$\widehat{\mathbf{x}} = \sum_i^m x_i G_i$ the corresponding hat-operator ($G_i$ the $i$th basis vector of the tangent space/Lie algebra $\frak{g}$) and $(\cdot)^\vee$ the inverse of $\widehat{\cdot}$:
 $$(X)^\vee := \text{ that } \mathbf{x} \text{ such that } \widehat{\mathbf{x}} = X.$$

Let us define the Lie bracket over $m$-vectors as: 
$[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}] = \left(\widehat{\mathbf{a}}\cdot\widehat{\mathbf{b}}-\widehat{\mathbf{b}}\cdot\widehat{\mathbf{a}}\right)^\vee$.

(Example: For $\frak{so}(3)$, $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}] = \mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}$ with $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.)

Is there a common name of the derivative:
$$\frac{\partial [\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}]}{\partial \mathbf{a}}$$?

Comment: How are the generators defined?  As images under a basis of the $\exp$ map?  And why is it that $\hat a \hat b - \hat b \hat a$ is necessarily a combination of generators of $G$?  I'm guessing though that this is just the bracket on $\mathfrak g$ (since at least what you have agrees up to highest order if you're using the notion of generators I mentioned).

Comment: The generators are simply a set of Cartesian basis vectors which span the tangent space.

Comment: I think you are conflating Lie groups and Lie algebras...

Comment: Because I called $G_i$ the generator of the "Lie group?" This is a common convention in physics, but I am happy to call $G_i$ just the basis vector of the tangent space/Lie algebra.

Comment: Eric, thanks for your comments. I understand that it can be very misleading to call $G_i$ generators of the Lie group, so I edited the OP.

Comment: Is $\cdot$ in $\hat a \cdot \hat b$ matrix multiplication?  If so then that bracket is the Lie algebra bracket and my answer below applies: it is linear in each variable so it's derivative (with respect to one variable) is itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it seems like you are asking for the derivative of the map
$$
\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g, ~~ a \mapsto [a, b]
$$
where $b \in \mathfrak g$ is fixed.  Since $\mathfrak g$ is a vector space, the derivative at a point can be viewed as a map $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g$.  But the above map is linear so it's its own derivative at any point.

Comment: So the point is, you implicitly say, that $[{\bf a},{\bf b}]$ as defined by the hat operator above just coincides with the original Lie bracket $[a,b]$ *in a way*, am I right?

Comment: Ah ok... actually I'm not sure-- it should be.  This notion is non-standard and I don't even see why it's well defined (see my comment to OP).

Comment: Anyways, as long as his bracket operation is still bilinear, my argument works.